# Crash Debug on LineageOS 14.1

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I just flashed my mobile with LineageOS 14.1

To my surprise I see the crashes that they dont show full stack trace.

Only this:

```
01-03 22:44:01.189 12773 12807 F libc : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x42424242 in tid 12807 (hci_thread)
```

Do I have to enable it somehow?

I would expect to see something like this (this I remember from Cyanogenmod and Stock Android)

```
02-05 16:45:13.279 307 1231 F libc : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x1 in tid 1231 (netmgrd)
02-05 16:45:13.351 6570 6570 F DEBUG : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-05 16:45:13.352 6570 6570 F DEBUG : CM Version: '14.1-20170131-NIGHTLY-osprey'
02-05 16:45:13.352 6570 6570 F DEBUG : Build fingerprint: 'motorola/osprey_retus_2gb/osprey_u2:6.0.1/MPI24.107-55/33:user/release-keys'
02-05 16:45:13.352 6570 6570 F DEBUG : Revision: '0'
02-05 16:45:13.352 6570 6570 F DEBUG : ABI: 'arm'
02-05 16:45:13.352 6570 6570 F DEBUG : pid: 307, tid: 1231, name: netmgrd >>> /system/bin/netmgrd <<<
02-05 16:45:13.352 6570 6570 F DEBUG : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1
02-05 16:45:13.352 6570 6570 F DEBUG : r0 b6b01f10 r1 00000001 r2 b6b06560 r3 00000040
02-05 16:45:13.352 6570 6570 F DEBUG : r4 b647f3fc r5 b6b06eac r6 b6b01f10 r7 b6b02d07
02-05 16:45:13.352 6570 6570 F DEBUG : r8 b5f07520 r9 b5f07500 sl 00000001 fp b6f7ea49
02-05 16:45:13.352 6570 6570 F DEBUG : ip 00000000 sp b647f000 lr b6af9ba5 pc b6af9bce cpsr 20070030
02-05 16:45:13.363 6570 6570 F DEBUG : 
02-05 16:45:13.363 6570 6570 F DEBUG : backtrace:
02-05 16:45:13.363 6570 6570 F DEBUG : #00 pc 00007bce /system/vendor/lib/libnetmgr.so (netmgr_nl_decode_nlmsg+269)
02-05 16:45:13.363 6570 6570 F DEBUG : #01 pc 00020f7d /system/bin/netmgrd
02-05 16:45:13.363 6570 6570 F DEBUG : #02 pc 00033893 /system/bin/netmgrd
02-05 16:45:13.364 6570 6570 F DEBUG : #03 pc 00041b09 /system/bin/netmgrd
02-05 16:45:13.364 6570 6570 F DEBUG : #04 pc 0000bef9 /system/vendor/lib/libdsutils.so (stm2_process_input+632)
02-05 16:45:13.364 6570 6570 F DEBUG : #05 pc 0000c7dd /system/vendor/lib/libdsutils.so (stm2_instance_process_input+204)
02-05 16:45:13.364 6570 6570 F DEBUG : #06 pc 0001213d /system/bin/netmgrd
02-05 16:45:13.364 6570 6570 F DEBUG : #07 pc 00003f9f /system/vendor/lib/libdsutils.so
02-05 16:45:13.364 6570 6570 F DEBUG : #08 pc 000477d3 /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
02-05 16:45:13.364 6570 6570 F DEBUG : #09 pc 00019b7d /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Had to modify debbugerd (bionic) and adjust selinux.

Now debuggerd can attach to the process and show the debug info and backtrace.